# PHP and cURL or otherwise. Can it retrieve JavaScript generated data?

Tags: php

I know this is very unlikely, but maybe there is another solution.

What I want to do is retrieve JavaScript generated data from an external website. This isn't for an exploit, but rather a test.

I noticed Google cannot index Ajax generated content.. but could they, and more importantly, how?

I guess that is a better way of putting it.

Comment: Ask a site owner for an RSS feed

Comment: I'm not trying to crawl sites Col.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can do it on a case-by-case basis. However you wouldn't use a tool like cURL. Instead, you'd use something more sophisticated like a browser or javascript interpreter (Rhino springs to mind) to interpret and run the JS and then retrieve the values from there.